# Should I include scala-compiler as a dependency in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to build a project with scala 2.11.7 in intellij. I've set the `scalaVersion` to `2.11.7`, but when I check the external libraries, I can see `scala-compiler:2.11.0`.

Do I need to declare `scala-compiler:2.11.7` as a dependency in `build.sbt`? The [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Configuring-Scala.html) are confusing, seemingly saying that I do need to and then not to in consecutive paragraphs:

> When using a Scala dependency other than the standard library, add it
>   as a normal managed dependency. For example, to depend on the Scala
>   compiler,
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" %
>   scalaVersion.value

and

> In order to compile Scala code, run scaladoc, and provide a Scala
>   REPL, sbt needs the scala-compiler jar. This should not be a normal
>   dependency of the project, so sbt adds a dependency on scala-compiler
>   in the special, private scala-tool configuration.

So... should I add it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project's code uses `scala-compiler` (e.g. to parse or compile Scala code, to run a REPL, etc.), add it. Otherwise, don't. That's why the first quote says "*When* using a Scala dependency other than the standard library..."

`scala-compiler` shown in External Libraries is probably there because one of your other dependencies depends on it (and that version was compiled with Scala 2.11.0).

Comment: So why am I seeing scala-compiler:2.11.0 in my external libs do you think? Is that jar actually being used to compile my project? I can see scala-library:2.11.7, so perhaps the compiler hasn't been updated since 2.11.0 (seems far-fetched)?

Comment: See the edit (I actually added it before seeing your comment).