# Embedding scala 2.13.x REPL

Tags: scala, scala-repl, scala-2.13

For Scala **2.12.x** one could use `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop` to embed the Scala REPL. With Scala **2.13.x** `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop` has been removed. How could one embed the Scala 2.13.x REPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding [`scala-compiler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414841/5205022) dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.13.1"
```

after which, for example, the following compiles

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.{ILoop, ShellConfig}
import scala.tools.nsc._

object EmbeddedREPL extend App {
  val settings = new Settings {
    usejavacp.value = true
    deprecation.value = true
  }
  val config = ShellConfig(settings)
  new ILoop(config).run(settings)
}
```